# Pulling certain directories in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

Let me try to make this really simple to follow. I'm deploying Vagrant for my developers and I'll be using Puppet to provision the machines. Let's say I have two sets of machines, one that has apache/mysql5 server and an apache/mongodb server. I use Puppet to manage the different components, but I am not using a centralized puppetmaster server.

With that said, I'm serving two directories inside a Mercurial repository. In the event I need to modify something with mysql, I can have the devs pull the latest changes accordingly. The issue I'm having is, how do I handle the repository structure without having to duplicate the directory structure.

`manifests`  - This is different for each machine, `mysql` machine will have directives to install `mysql` while the `mongodb` machine will have its own instructions for `mongodb`

`modules` - This is shared among every machine, but only the required folders inside this folder is stored on each machine (i.e. modules/mongodb and modules/mysql).

If I threw all this into one big repository, I don't want my "apache+mysql" server to download  modules for the "apache+mongodb" modules. Is there a way to let's say put the `manifests` directory into a particular repo and download only the appropriate folders from the `modules` folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Subrepository](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository) functionnality of Mercurial.

If I understand correctly what you want, I'll do the following :

1. One repository for each various manifest
2. One repository for each various modules
3. Create a "top level" repository for each machine type which will contains the various needed subrepositories from above.